# Sorting columns with strings in excel file [with python,pandas]

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm quite newbie with pandas and im looking for sorting and comparing columns, but i want to sort strings.
I want to sort strings, and leave empty spaces like it was
Do you have any ideas guys? I was wondering to do something with code below, but i dont know what to do next with that

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
print(df.query('a != b'))

INPUT: 
  a b
1 A C
2 B D
3 D 
4 C A

OUTPUT: 
  a b
1 A A
2 B 
3 D D
4 C C
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please check my solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need find the correct order of the series b using [Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html). Finally replace using [Series.replace](http://%20%20[1]:%20https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
df['b']=df['a'].map(pd.Series(df.index,df['b'].values)).replace(df['b'])
print(df)
```

---

```
   a    b
0  A    A
1  B  NaN
2  D    D
3  C    C
```

---

if you want to order following the dictionary you need to order first based on the column a using [DataFrame.sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df=df.sort_values('a')
df['b']=df['a'].map(pd.Series(df.index,df['b'].values)).replace(df['b'])
print(df)
```

---

```
   a    b
0  A    A
1  B  NaN
3  C    C
2  D    D
```

Also you can use [DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with **`sort = False`**:

```
new_df=df['a'].to_frame().merge(df['b'].to_frame(),left_on='a',right_on='b',how='outer',indicator=True,sort=False).query('_merge!="right_only"').drop('_merge',axis=1)
print(new_df)
```

---

```
  a    b
0  A    A
1  B  NaN
2  D    D
3  C    C
```

or with **`sort = True`**

```
new_df=df['a'].to_frame().merge(df['b'].to_frame(),left_on='a',right_on='b',how='outer',indicator=True).query('_merge!="right_only"').drop('_merge',axis=1)
    print(new_df)

-----------------------

      a    b
    0  A    A
    1  B  NaN
    2  C    C
    3  D    D
```

Comment: I am glad to hlep You !. Could you upvote and/or accept?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example, it seems you just want to find out where there are no exact matches but retain the sort order.  You can achieve by using this:

```
df['b'] = df['a'].where(df['a'].isin(df['b']), '')

>>> df

   a  b
0  A  A
1  B   
2  D  D
3  C  C

>>>> df.query('a != b')

   a  b 
1  B
```